# Creating a subplot of complex plots (more then 2 lines)

Tags: plot, figure

I'm trying to figure out how to take four plots I've created that have about 6 different lines plotted on them and I want to take these plots and create a subplot of all of these but I'm having trouble because they have 6 different lines on each figure. I've tried doing subplot but since theres 6 different things to be plotted in each figure I'm not sure how to do it.. I've also tried copyobj but ran into the same problem.. any ideas?
Below is an example of one of the four figures to be plotted.

```
if dofig2==1

fig=figure(2); clf; grid on; axis equal; hold on;
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');title('Mohrs Circle for Strian'); 
p2 = plot( HI(:,1), HI(:,2));
set(p2,'Color','k','LineWidth',2);

p2 = scatter(c,0);
set(p2,'MarkerEdgeColor','r','LineWidth',6);

p2 = plot(xaxis,yaxis,'--');
set(p2,'Color','y','LineWidth',2);

p2 = plot(plotline1,plotline2,'-');
set(p2,'Color','g','LineWidth',2);

p2 = line(paxis1,paxis2);
set(p2,'Color','c','LineWidth',2);

p2 = line(paxis3,paxis4);
set(p2,'Color','magenta','LineWidth',2);
legend('mohrs circle ','center','e1-e2','ymin-ymax','principle axis','eaa-ebb')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to plot different subplots, you must use the [`subplot`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) function.

It takes 3 arguments: number of subplots vertically, number of subplots horizontally and the id of the current one you want to plot.

Then, in each subplot, if you want to put more than one thing you should use [`hold on`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html?searchHighlight=hold%20on) before the subplots.

Example:

```
y=rand(1,10);
y2=rand(1,10);


subplot(1,2,1)
hold on

plot(1:10,y,'g')
plot(1:10,y2,'r*')

subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(imread('cameraman.tif'))
```

[image]